# How is the begining of century considered?

Tags: hadith, revelation

> At the beginning of every century Allah will send to this ummah someone who will renew its religious understanding.”
>   Narrated by Abu Dawood (4291); classed as saheeh by as-Sakhkhaawi in al-Maqaasid al-Hasanah (149) and by al-Albaani in as-Silsilah as-Saheehah (no. 599).

Does the counting starts after death of prophet? Or after end of raashidun caliphate?

I'm asking this because during siege of kaaba in 80's they used the above hadith and the day was muharram 1, 1400 hijri and declared a person named muhammad as mahdi

Comment: Medi1Saif's answer covers some scholarly commentary on the issue.

Comment: @UmH, the question you mentioned and the above are related to same hadith,  but are entirely different. Above question is asking about methodology of considering hundred years, the question you mentioned answers about source, authenticity and text.

Comment: This part: واختلف في رأس المائة هل يعتبر من المولد النبوي أو البعثة أو الهجرة أو الوفاة Basically there are different opinions on this, there is no correct answer.